# Restrictions after you failover to an upgraded server instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, mirroring

**Restrictions after you failover to an upgraded server instance**.
Can some one please explain this is detail? "After failing over from an earlier server instance to a SQL Server 2016 server instance, the database session is suspended. It cannot be resumed until the other partner has been upgraded".

Answer (score 3):

> After failing over from an earlier server instance to a SQL Server 2016 server instance, the database session is suspended.

Once you failover to the 2016 instance, the database is now upgraded fully to 2016. This is a one way trip and will no longer be able to be hosted on anything but SQL Server 2016. Since the partner is not 2016, the data movement will be suspended (stopped). No new data will "flow" back to the older instance.

> It cannot be resumed until the other partner has been upgraded

Until the old principal server (now the mirror server) is upgraded to 2016 you will not be able to resume data movement - no data will flow until you upgrade the older instance to 2016 and manually resume the data movement.

Comment: Is this specific to sql server 2016 or will the same apply while upgrading to sql server 2014?

Comment: So what you are saying is that there won't be any mirroring until and unless both the servers are upgraded to the same server version.

Comment: @RajVikramSingh It applies any time you upgrade one of the instances participating in mirroring, regardless of version. So 208 to 2008r2 or r2 to 2012, etc. Yes, that's exactly what it's saying; there will be no mirroring going on after you fail over to the higher version until the other server is on the same version.